# Spring ControllerAdvice does not handle Exception from static method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've the following method:

```
static <T extends Enum<T> & IEnum> T getEnumFromString(Class<T> c, String value) throws EnumException {
    T[] values = c.getEnumConstants();
    for (T v : values) {
        if (v.getStringValue().equals(value)) {
            return v;
        }
    }

    throw new EnumException(String.format("[%s] enum does not have value [%s]", c.getSimpleName(), value));
}
```

Which is called during serialization.

The `EnumException extends Exception`

My controller method:

```
public ResponseEntity<Transaction> validateTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction transaction){
   ...
}
```

Transaction class:

```
public class Transaction {

    private TransactionType transactionType;
    private String iban;
    private String cnp;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Float sum;

    public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) throws EnumException {
        this.transactionType = TransactionType.fromString(transactionType);
    }
    ...
}
```

In this setter, the `EnumException` is thrown

While debugging the `@ControllerAdvice` method, I see that it is calling the `handleException(...)` method from **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** class instead of my method

In the case the `EnumException` is thrown, I get the 400 status code and empty response body.

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(EnumException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleIllegalArgumentException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    String errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
    Map<String, Object> responseBody = buildResponseBody(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errorMessage);
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, responseBody, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
}
}
```

Why the exception handler method is not executed?

Here are the logs:

```
POST "/transaction", parameters={}
2019-08-01 16:54:46.429 DEBUG 11349 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.orange.validator.model.Transaction> com.orange.validator.controller.TransactionController.validateTransaction(com.orange.validator.model.Transaction)
2019-08-01 16:54:50.262 DEBUG 11349 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.orange.validator.model.Transaction> com.orange.validator.controller.TransactionController.validateTransaction(com.orange.validator.model.Transaction): JSON parse error: [TransactionType] enum does not have value [sdsds]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: [TransactionType] enum does not have value [sdsds]
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 7, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.orange.validator.model.Transaction["transactionType"])
2019-08-01 16:54:50.272 DEBUG 11349 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2019-08-01 16:54:50.300 DEBUG 11349 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : No match for [*/*], supported: []
2019-08-01 16:54:50.305 DEBUG 11349 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: [TransactionType] enum does not have value [sdsds]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: [TransactionType] enum does not have value [sdsds]
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 7, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.orange.validator.model.Transaction["transactionType"])]
2019-08-01 16:54:50.306 DEBUG 11349 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

Comment: post your `Transaction` class and your full stacktrace during the exception. Jackson probably wraps your exception in something when throwing it.

Comment: updated, no stack trace

Comment: there is a stack trace run you application in debug and set `logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG` in your `application.properties`

Comment: editted the question

Comment: it is calling the handleException() method from the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class

Comment: `HttpMessageNotReadableException` this is the exception that is thrown. You see jackson throws a `JsonMappingException` that spring then wraps.

Comment: `EnumException` -> `JsonMappingException` -> `HttpMessageNotReadableException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to Override the `handleHttpMessageNotReadable(...)` method from the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class.

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    IllegalArgumentException exception = (IllegalArgumentException) ex.getMostSpecificCause();
    String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
    Map<String, Object> responseBody = buildResponseBody(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errorMessage);
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, responseBody, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
}
```

To get the error message, I am casting the `HttpMessageNotReadableException` to my thrown exception and getting the right error message

Answer (score 1):

use @ResponseBody to

```
@ExceptionHandler(EnumException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleIllegalArgumentException(Exception ex, W...
```

or try this

```
@ExceptionHandler({ Throwable.class })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(final Throwable e, final webrequest request) {
       String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
       Map<String, Object> responseBody = buildResponseBody(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errorMessage);
       return handleExceptionInternal(e, responseBody, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
```